# Regex to only accept 2, 6 and 7 at the begining and 8 numbers total

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to validate a field in Laravel 5 here's the validation string:

```
'required|min:8|max:8|regex:/^[267]\d{8}$/'
```

I keep getting the validation error message, what is the problem? is the regex malformed?

Comment: `[267]` is one digit already.

Comment: What *validation error message* are you getting? What is the **exact** message?

Comment: @KenWhite the message is: `The tel format is invalid.`

Comment: @bobblebubble mmm, then how do i validate the first number to be 2, 6 or 7?

Comment: That was the trick @KenWhite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is `^[267]\d{7}$`, which validates a single digit that is either 2, 6, or 7 followed by 7 additional digits (a total of 8 digits combined).